# How To Read an .rtf via a StreamReader Ignoring the .rtf file formatting ? (Not Maintaining it)

Tags: c#, rtf, streamreader

I have a `StreamReader` reading from a `.txt`, `.rtf` and `.docx` files.
I store what is read in a `string` variable, then I print this variable to a `RichTextBox`
the problem is that my `RichTextBox` `BackColor` is Black and the `ForeColor` is Green,
so if the text color in the `.rtf` file is black, it won't be visible in the TextBox, 
not to mention that it won't use the Font that I specified in my TextBox !

Maybe I could just use a normal TextBox, not a RichTextBox, but that way I won't be able to Color the text in the TextBox...

How Can I fix That ?

Comment: I think you can still color the text in a textbox somehow.  Aside from that, you might look into stripping the formatting from the incoming string somehow.

Comment: Are you setting this text to the RichTextBox using the `Rtf` property?

Comment: @Andre Calil No, as I said, I'm just reading the text from the file, then to a string variable, then: RichTextBoxName.Text = myStringVariable;

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to have a second, invisible, `RichTextBox` on the form. Read the RTF from the `StreamReader`, store it in the hidden text box, then read the text from the hidden text box and write it to the visible one. Something like:

```
string rtfText = File.ReadAllText(filename);
hiddenTextBox.Rtf = rtfText;
visibleTextBox.Text = hiddenTextBox.Text;
```

Not exactly elegant, but it handles the nasty work of stripping the formatting for you.

Comment: That's what I was going to suggest =)

Comment: @Jim Mischel hmm, Didn't really work, It's still taking the formatting.
And the strange thing is that When I read The contents of the rtf file (which contains Arabic words), the Invisible RichTextBox displayed the text as some kinda Chinese or something, when I read the visible RichTextBox text from the invisible one, I got the Original Text in the rtf file with its formatting maintained.

Comment: you know what, I have an Idea, I'll create a new .txt file, write to it the value of the string variable that i read from the .rtf file, then read it back again..

Comment: Also didn't work, I guess when I use the Encoding.Unicode option it takes the format with it ..